# by npm compilation it changes the image path

Tags: laravel-5, npm, sass

I am using the Laravel framework with npm.
In the scss file i have image path:

```
background-image: url("../../img/frontend/payments.png");
```

by compilation when I open the styles.css and look for that image the path is the following:

```
background-image: url(/images/payments.png?464788fabc66a26cf02344b0dcbcdde2);
```

How can I change that path, because all my images are in img/ folder.

There is another thing which is bothering me. I need to copy the payments.png in the resources/sass folder, which is copying tha that picture in public/images. So i have the duplicate of each picture. Is it somehow possible to stay all my images in the public/img folder ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel mix, the urls change because of the webpack url processing.
You can read more about it in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#url-processing).

**tldr**

```js
mix.options({
    processCssUrls: false
});
```

And about the duplicate resources (like the pictures you mentioned): Keep the original resources in the *resources* directory and copy them using Laravel mix to the *public* folder. The reason behind this is sometimes you want to process the resources and then copy them. for example first optimize the png files then copy them to the public folder while keeping the original file in the resources directory.